# Event Response not firing anonymous user

Tags: 8, caching, event-subscribers

I have a module in drupal8 which only job is on an event response is to redirect a URL. It works fine for everyone except anonymous users. How do I give the module privileges to fire on every user no matter if the are logged in or not.

This is the geographic_me_redirect.services.yml

```
services:
  me_redirect.process_me_request:
    class: Drupal\me_redirect\EventSubscriber\ResponseSubscriber
    arguments: []
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

This is the response

```
class ResponseSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{


    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {

        ///$events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onRouteMatch', 27];
        //-- fires the event in the kernal early oo page load 20
        $events[KernelEvents::RESPONSE] = ['process_language_request',0];
        //-- For redirecting to another domain

        return $events;
    }



    public function process_language_request(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {

    return my logic

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you  explain more about method **process_language_request**, condition, process you want?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this when the redirect is already stored in the internal page cache. Because anonymous traffic is served from this cache before any event is fired.

You have to use this kill switch:

```
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
```

If you put this in your event subscriber and clear the cache, then you prevent, that the response is cached in the internal page cache.

Comment: Not sure where others have placed `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();` but it worked for me to add to the constructor `__construct()`.

Comment: @Duncanmoo, while you can use this kill switch almost anywhere, I meant with event subscriber in this example `process_language_request(FilterResponseEvent $event)`, not the class, because you can put multiple event subscribers in one class.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want redirect to URL you can use class like this:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_event\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableMetadata;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

/**
 * Class MyEventSubscriber.
 *
 * @package Drupal\my_event
 */
class MyEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['processEvent', 0];
    return $events;
  }

  /**
   * Redirect and cache with anonymous user
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Url $url
   */
  protected function setResponse(GetResponseEvent $event, Url $url) {
    $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse($url->toString(), 301);
    $response->addCacheableDependency(CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray([])
      ->addCacheTags(['rendered']));
    $event->setResponse($response);
  }

  /**
   * Process with difference condition
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event
   */
  public function processEvent(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $logic = $this->checkLogic();
    if ($logic) {
      $this->setResponse($event, Url::fromUri("https://www.example.com"));
    }
  }

  /**
   * Check logic redirect
   * @return boolean logic
   */
  protected function checkLogic() {
    return $logic;
  }
}
```

Magic here is method **setResponse**. I use event **KernelEvents::REQUEST** and set cache in method **setResponse**. It's working with anonymous user.

Comment: Hi, this is working great except for the redirects keeps looping could you give me an example inside the checklogic(). I am assuming that it stops an. The redirect from looping. Also with this could use $response = new RedirectResponse($url); $response->send();

Comment: what's condition you want redirect to url?